# How to align columns in a table printed on PDF document?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

This is my code to generate records in pdf. I need to show records one by one, but this code has no control on column width for pdfptable. How to set it?

I used `Itext` to generate PDF.

```
pdfDocument=new Document();

PdfWriter.getInstance(pdfDocument, new FileOutputStream(sOutputDirectory + "/" + sOutputFileName, false));       
pdfDocument.open();
if(valuelist!=null && !valuelist.isEmpty() && valuelist!=null && !valuelist.isEmpty() && pdfDocument.isOpen() ){
    System.out.println("CP 1");

    PdfPTable pdfPTable=new PdfPTable(valuelist.size());
    pdfPTable.setWidthPercentage(100);
    float[] columnWidths = new float[] {15f, 15f, 15f, 35f,15f,15f};
    pdfPTable.setWidths(columnWidths);
    PdfPCell pdfPCell;

    for(int i=0;i<valuelist.size();i++){

        System.out.println("CP :"+i);

        Bean bean = (Bean) valuelist.get(i);
        pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bean.getsName()));
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);

        pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bean.getsNumber()));
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);

        pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bean.getsTransactionDate()));
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);

        pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bean.getsItemNo()));
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);

        pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bean.getsPoints()));
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);

        pdfPCell=new PdfPCell(new Phrase(bean.getsQuantity()));
        pdfPCell.setBorder(Rectangle.NO_BORDER);
        pdfPTable.addCell(pdfPCell);
    }

    pdfDocument.add(pdfPTable);
}
pdfDocument.close();
```

Comment: What do you want as a result and in which way does the result of your code not fulfill that?

Comment: Sorry for late reply mkl. Actually i need to show six columns per row. The problem is i have set the Array list size as PDFP Table value. Now it works fine